# SQL LIKE Column Value Plus Wildcard DB2

Tags: db2, wildcard, sql-like

I'm trying to use a column and a wildcard in a LIKE clause. I was expecting this to work:

```
WHERE COLUMNA LIKE '%'||COLUMNB||'%'
```

Is this supported in DB2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be able to use the locate syntax (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/fsubstr.htm)

```
WHERE LOCATE(COLUMNB,COLUMNA) > 0
```