# DB2 10 for Z/OS, SQL LIKE Column Value Plus Wildcard DB2 w/o losing stage 1

Tags: sql, db2, zos

So, this is related to [SQL LIKE Column Value Plus Wildcard DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807593/sql-like-column-value-plus-wildcard-db2), but a more specific question b/c of the OS

So, I want to:

```
select a.columnA
       b.columnZ
from a
join table b
  on b.columnB LIKE a.columnA || '%'
```

b.columnB is an Index and I'd like the join to be done using that (b/c it is a massive table). But sadly z/OS doesn't allow using a column on the right side of the LIKE.

From the other post, I realize I can use LOCATE, but it is a scalar function and therefore does not qualify as a stage 1 predicate, so I lose the value of the index.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: You want all the rows from B where columnB is a SUBSTR of columnA (starting from the left)? Will this be correct if it matches A with AA, AB, ABCDEFG, AZZZZ etc? So there can be many a rows for each b row?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a range predicate and concatenate high values onto the end of the column value for the high end of the range.  This is equivalent to the like predicate:

```
select a.columnA
       b.columnZ
from a
join table b
  on b.columnB >= a.columnA 
 and b.columnB <  a.columnA || x'FF'
```

This is something we use often where I work specifically to be able to use indexes on a partial value match like this.